# How to get date counts while considering n consecutive date ranges as single count in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example there is some table with dates:

```
2022-01-01
2022-01-02
2022-01-03
2022-01-06
2022-01-07
2022-01-11
```

I have to write SQL query, which will return count of dates between date ranges and consider consecutive dates as a single count. So the result will be like:

consider single count if 2 consecutive dates

```
2022-01-01 1
2022-01-02 1
2022-01-03 2
2022-01-06 3
2022-01-07 3
2022-01-11 4
```

consider single count if 3 consecutive dates

```
2022-01-01 1
2022-01-02 1
2022-01-03 1
2022-01-06 2
2022-01-07 3
2022-01-11 4
```

consider single count if 4 consecutive dates

```
2022-01-01 1
2022-01-02 2
2022-01-03 3
2022-01-06 4
2022-01-07 4
2022-01-08 4
2022-01-09 4
2022-01-10 5
2022-01-13 6
```

consider single count if n consecutive dates
n is configurable

Comment: Why for `3 consecutive dates`, `2022-01-07` is `3` and not `2`?

Comment: this consecutive dates can be 2,3,4,...
3 consecutive dates, 2022-01-07 is 3 and not 2
only if 3 consecutive dates occur then only we can consider as single count. if not we can take it as individual count

Comment: Can you also include samples and expected result for 4 consecutive dates

Comment: added expected result for 4 consecutive dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution first identify group of consecutive dates. And then break it into the required `"n"` consecutive dates

The description are in the comments. It is break up into few cte so it is easier to examine the value at each stage.

---

```
declare @n int = 3;

with cte as
(
  -- find when the date is not consecutive 
  -- using lag() to compare with current row
  select [date], 
         g = case when dateadd(day, -1, [date])
                  <>   lag([date]) over (order by [date])
                  then 1
                  else 0
                  end
  from   dates
),
cte2 as
(
  -- group conecusive dates together 
  -- by sum up g
  select *, grp = sum(g) over (order by [date])
  from   cte
),
cte3 as
(
  -- break the group by @n
  select *, rn = (row_number() over (partition by grp order by [date]) - 1) / @n
  from   cte2
)
-- dense_rank() to number it
select *, [count] = dense_rank() over (order by grp, rn)
from   cte3
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/11FzW11G)

---

EDIT: misunderstood your requirement. This should gives you the required result

```
with cte as
(
  -- find when the date is not consecutive  
  -- using lag() to compare with current row
  select [date], 
         g = case when dateadd(day, -1, [date])
                  <>   lag([date]) over (order by [date])
                  then 1
                  else 0
                  end
  from   dates
),
cte2 as
(
  -- group consecutive dates together 
  -- by sum up g
  select *, grp = sum(g) over (order by [date])
  from   cte
),
cte3 as
(
  -- count number of consecutive dates in a group
  select *, 
         c = count(*) over (partition by grp)
  from   cte2
),
cte4 as
(
  select *,
         rn = case when c >= @n
                   then (row_number() over (partition by grp order by [date]) - 1) / @n
                   else row_number() over (partition by grp order by [date])
                   end
  from   cte3
)
select *, [count] = dense_rank() over (order by grp, rn)
from   cte4
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/YDlXn_X6)

Comment: seems for declare @n int = 3; it is giving wrong results
it should be 2022-01-11 4
I will validate with logic thanks